# What are the ways to run qpid c example without make?

Tags: c++, apache, message-queue

What are the ways to  run apache qpid c++ helloworld example without make and by using g++ i need to create an helloworld.o object file how to do these?

g++ -I ./includes/ -o m hello_world.cpp

```
/tmp/cc9Jao8f.o: In function `main':
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::Connection(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::open()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::createSession(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Session::createReceiver(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Session::createSender(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Message::Message(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Sender::send(qpid::messaging::Message const&, bool)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Message::~Message()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Message::~Message()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Duration::SECOND'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::operator*(qpid::messaging::Duration const&, unsigned long)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x2f7): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Receiver::fetch(qpid::messaging::Duration)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x30d): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Message::getContent() const'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Session::acknowledge(bool)'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::close()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x389): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Message::~Message()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x39f): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Message::~Message()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Sender::~Sender()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x3d2): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Sender::~Sender()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x3e8): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Receiver::~Receiver()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x3ff): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Receiver::~Receiver()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x415): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Session::~Session()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Session::~Session()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x483): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::close()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x4b5): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::~Connection()'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x4cc): undefined reference to `qpid::messaging::Connection::~Connection()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to link against the library.  If the library is called `libqpid.so` for example, you would add `-lqpid` to your build command.

Comment: but i need i run a apache qpid example without make and using g++ how to do ?http://people.apache.org/~jonathan/High-Level-API.html#id3063300

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.